# Is the absolute value of distance covariance a metric?

Tags: covariance, metric, distance-covariance

I'm reasonably certain the absolute value of the distance covariance satisfies

1. $d(x, y) \ge 0$     (non-negativity, or separation axiom)
2. $d(x, y) = 0$   if and only if   $x = y$     (identity of indiscernibles, or coincidence axiom)
3. $d(x, y) = d(y, x)$     (symmetry)

But I'm not sure about:

4) $d(x, z) \le d(x, y) + d(y, z)$     (subadditivity / triangle inequality).

I'm thinking in particular of a space of timeseries, but I don't think that matters too much.

Answer (score 4):

If by distance covariancen you mean this

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance_correlation#Distance_covariance

then the point 2. is false. There are many possibilities for this distance to be 0.

Comment: Ok. Obviously my understanding is pretty limited. Could you give a simple example?

Answer (score 2):

Distance covariance and distance Correlation do not satisfy the triangular inequality. 
Pearson's correlation itself on centered data or otherwise, does not satisfy the inequality, and hence is known as a semi-metric.

Comment: This appears to conflict with Münchhausen answer.

Comment: It does not. Münchhausen deals with point 2. Mine deals with point 4. Münchhausen says that if x,y are statistically dependent, yet unequal. dCov(x,y) can be zero.

Comment: I meant the "semi-metric" comment. A semi-metric DOES satisfy point 2.

Comment: Also, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance_correlation says "[distance correlation] is zero if and only if the random variables are statistically independent"

Comment: If you read again on what I said-The semi-metric, was about the Pearson's correlation. Distance Correlation and Pearson's Correlation are different.

Comment: I know you were talking about Pearson's, but Pearson's correlation coefficient can clearly be 0 when x!=y..

Comment: Ok-that was a misuse of terminology. Pearson's correlation cannot be a semimetric because of the iff condition over 2.

Answer (score 1):

You got it: covariance, of course, induces a metric:
$$
d(x,y) = \sqrt{ \text{Cov}(x-y,x-y) }
$$
but NOT: 
$$
d(x,y) = \text{Cov}(x,y)
$$
Actually I'm thinking about the property of the triangle inequality. Or, what effect does this property induce?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, from doing some more reading, the assumption in the question is wrong. Covariance [actually defines an inner product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance#Relationship_to_inner_products), if (as I understand it) you first remove the mean of each variable. That is, covariance satisfies the following:

1. Conjugate symmetry: $Cov(X,Y) = Cov(Y,X)$
2. Linearity in the first argument: $Cov(aX+bY,Z) = a\cdot Cov(X,Z) + b\cdot Cov(Y,Z)$
3. Positive semi-definiteness: $Cov(X,X) = 0$ with equality only for X constant (This is where the removal of the mean comes in: $Cov(X,Y) = \langle X-\bar{X},Y-\bar{Y}\rangle$, such that $Var(X) = 0 \iff X_i = \bar{X}\ \forall\ i$ [X is constant, so removing the mean gives the zero vector])

This inner product induces a **norm**, also with the mean of the random variable removed: $\|X-\bar{X}\| = Var(X)$

And the norm in turn induces a **metric**: $d(X,Y) = \|(X-\bar{X})-(Y-\bar{Y})\| = Var(X-Y)$

So in a sense, Covariance *does* define a metric, just not in the way I first thought. It's been a whole 6 months since I studies any linear algebra, so I might have some of those slightly screwed up. Please correct me if I'm wrong!

The same applies to distance covariance, as is pretty clear from [the wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance_covariance#Distance_covariance_2), although it's a different inner product.

Comment: Although a covariance defines an inner product (Parzen, 1961), it is only SEMI-definite. To be a metric, you need strict definiteness. (e.g. zero covariance doesn't imply identically distributed random variables.) I agree with @Münchhausen that this is not the case for distance covariances, unless you consider a equivalence class of zero (distance) covariance random variables.

Comment: The "positive semi-definite" aspect is defined as the inner product of X *with itself*. How can it *not* be identically distributed?